# Phone Gap or native Android wrapper?

Tags: android, cordova, web-applications, mobile

I want to develop an application which works both in a regular browser and as an Android app. Both seem suitable but would I be right in saying if I went with Phone Gap, deploying the same html content as a regular, server hosted website is not trivial and would require modification? Also, are multi page applications not desirable in a Phone Gap wrapper?

Are there any alternatives I should consider? I'm surprised someone hasn't already written an Android wrapper with all the hardware access wiring done already. Or have they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you should know,

1. If you are going to publish your app also on iOS, you can't use server hosted website for your app. 
   All of your basic functionality must stand on your app assets, is one of the iOS guidelines, and its also make-sense for best ui performance (both iOS & Android).
   Use server-side wisely, when you want to fetch data which have to be up-to-date.
2. there are some new mobile browser features which will be available in the future, that allow your website to use the device hardware functions:
   [Device API on W3C](http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/)

Good luck dude ;)

Comment: I don't have any intention of supporting iOS and supporting separate mobile/desktop UIs seem like a headache. It's more of a learning experience. I'm all for writing purely Web apps but if I do decide to monetise it, it needs a shiny icon on the desktop and live in an app store, otherwise people just don't use it. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jquery mobile framework:

http://www.jquerymobile.com

It is jquery based framework for developing web apps that works on standard web and on multiple mobile devices (with cordova)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this would allow me to publish the same app to a desktop browser and a mobile device, or an I missing something?